# How to REMOVE the splitting of text (output) in c++?

Tags: c++

I would like to know if there's a way to remove the splitting of text in the output in c++? For example in this pic,

[image: too long text for terminal]

the program ask me to input an amount and it will print the alphabet 'a' in that amount. So the input was 900 and thus the program printed 'a' 900 times but with splitting. I want that the program prints 'a' in just **ONE single line**.

The reason why I'm asking this is because I'm making a program which will print a certain command (I just need to copy-paste the output) some numbers of time and if those commands are split like this then they wouldn't just work.

Thanks.

Comment: You're talking about line wrapping. And it's entirely up to your terminal program. There may be some way to change it.

Comment: Looks like CodeBlocks's console. I'd imagine it uses the OS's and wraps stuff on top.

Comment: Yep I'm using code::blocks.

Comment: @DotNetZeZo If anyone is able to resolve your question, remember to accept that answer.  It looks like you've never done that, which will keep bringing people to your questions because it looks like they were never resolved.

Comment: I've actually edited the screen buffer size to a high number and it works. But I only wanted to know if there's a certain code in c++ which can do that. Anyways, thanks everyone. Cheers!

Comment: Oh, forgot about that. There is a function for that in the Windows API, assuming you're using Windows. `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize` or something.

Comment: Oh yeah that was something I was searching for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of is changing the size of the terminal window.

To do this: **right-click on the status bar** > **Properties** > **Layout** > **Window Size** > **increase width**.

This may not be what you want, but it may help a bit.  Of course, this is also limited by the size of your monitor.

Comment: I've done that too, but I'm asking if there's a code or something for that and not re sizing the window.

Comment: @DotNetZeZo, There's code for resizing the window in Windows, but no word wrap toggle that I know of.

Comment: @DotNetZeZo the code has no control over that wrapping.  Code::Blocks is taking your program's unwrapped output and wrapping it in that particular window.

Comment: Yeah I just figured out that. Thanks a lot anyways.

Comment: No problem.  I think this was an interesting question.  Also, you do have the option of answering your own question (if you did find a satisfactory solution yourself).  If you haven't found a solution, you can just wait for someone to provide a solution.